# Check xls file not exist

Tags: c#, file

How can i check there are no xls found in the directory? I tried the code below, but it doesn't work...

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(".xls"))
{
   MessageBox.Show("No XLS dile found");
}
```

Comment: ***Duplicate question was 4 years old.*** Jon Skeet answers with new Directory.EnumerateFiles method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently you're looking for a *single* file called `.xls`. You should instead use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233.aspx):

```
if (!Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*.xls").Any())
{
    ...
}
```

Or if you're going to want the files anyway, use [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx):

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.xls");
if (files.Length == 0)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    // Handle the files
}
```

(Note that `EnumerateFiles` was introduced in .NET 4; you can use `GetFiles` in both cases of course, it's just cleaner to use `EnumerateFiles` when you can.)

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
            if (!System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\path", "*.xls", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No XLS dile found");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (!Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xls").Any()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do

```
if (!System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop", "*.xls", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any())
{
    Console.WriteLine("*.xls files not found");
}
else
{
    Console.Write("*.xls files exist");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not perfect, but simple :)

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
if(!files.Any(x=>x.EndsWith(".xls")))
{
   MessageBox.Show("No XLS dile found");
}
```